# jquery slideUP/DOWN working funny

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code below, when I select the radio button marked 'yes' it does slide down. But when I click on the one marked 'no' it doesn't slide up. Why is this?

html:

```
<label>Yes</label><input type="radio" name="teacher" id="teacher" value="yes"/>
<label>No</label><input type="radio" name="teacher" id="teacher" value="no"/><br>
```

jquery:

```
$("#teacher").click(function() {    
    if($(this).val() === "yes")
    {
        $("#teacher-info").slideDown();
    }
    else if($(this).val() === "no")
    {
        $("#teacher-info").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: `id` attributes should be unique within an HTML document. Instead of having your radio buttons share an id, use a `class` attribute or the `input:radio` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two elements with an `id` of `teacher`.

`id` is meant to be a unique property (only one element has one particular `id`) and jQuery assumes that to be true. If you have two elements with the same `id`, jQuery always picks the first one.

That being said, the solution to your problem is to change the `id` to a `class`, which is designed to be used for many elements.

**HTML**:

```
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="teacher" class="teacher" value="yes"/>

<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" name="teacher" class="teacher" value="no"/>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(".teacher").click(function() {    
    if($(this).val() === "yes")
    {
        $("#teacher-info").slideDown();
    }
    else if($(this).val() === "no")
    {
        $("#teacher-info").slideUp();
    }
});
```

By the way, since your radio buttons have only two states (`yes` and `no`), your code can be simplified:

```
$(".teacher").click(function() {    
    if ($(this).val() === "yes") {
        $("#teacher-info").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#teacher-info").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting `radiobutton` values in Jquery you can simply do:

```
$('input:radio[name=teacher]:checked').val();
```

First of all change your code and add an `class`:

```
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="teacher" class="teacher" value="yes"/>

<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" name="teacher" class="teacher" value="no"/>
```

So now change your code like this:

```
$(".teacher").click(function() {  
    var btnValue = $('input:radio[name=teacher]:checked').val()
    if(btnValue === "yes")
    {
        $("#teacher-info").slideDown();
    }
    else if(btnValue === "no")
    {
        $("#teacher-info").slideUp();
    }
});
```